# Can I say "in the Morning, last Sunday"

Tags: time, dates

When I say like this: I met him last Sunday morning.

Can I say alternatively: I met him **on last Sunday morning** or **on the morning of last Sunday** or **in the morning, last Sunday**?

Answer (score 1):

A native speaker would most likely say:

> I met him last Sunday morning.

or

> I met him last Sunday, in the morning.

This:

> On last Sunday morning

is grammatically correct, but wouldn't be used that often. Although you could say it, it would sound a bit strange and a native speaker mostly wouldn't use it. You would just say 'last Sunday morning', without the preposition.

> On the morning on last Sunday

This is also grammatically correct, but is really clunky and it would be a dead giveaway that you're not a native speaker.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for describing detailedly the grammars for me. Give you a thumbs up:)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all versions of the sentence are correct.